# Oque posso usar para diferenciar duas requisições POST no php

Tags: php, post, request

Estou fazendo um sistema web com php, que possui um desvio condicional para verificar se a requisição é um post repetido ou não, fiz isso para garantir que não iria ficar dando vários inserts repetidos no banco de dados, porém tem uma parte do sistema que precisa deixar repetir a requisição post mesmo se ela estiver repetindo, e isso não está acontecendo, emfim as questões são:

Como o servidor diferencia uma requisição POST e
Como posso fazer para diferenciar essa requisição post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso depende muito da estrutura do seu código. Mas uma ideia seria passar um campo Hidden do HTML, com um código específico. Com base nesse codigo passado através do campo hidden você poderia permitir ou não a inserção repetida;

Exemplo:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="tipo_insercao" value="unica"/>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

O PHP iria reagir mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['tipo_insercao'])){
       $tipo_insercao = $_POST['tipo_insercao'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];

       //Aqui fazemos o que for preciso com os dados. Inserir no banco?

       if($tipo_insercao=="unica"){
           unset($_POST);
       }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Manda um outro parâmetro via post, por exemplo executarRepeticao, caso ele for true você executa, senão, não executa.

Comment: Não entendi, tens como postar um exemplo de código?

Comment: A pergunta acima resolveu o meu problema